# How to debug (large) memory allocation in C

Tags: c, linux, gdb, coredump

I'm running a C program which is occupying large physical memory and I want to debug where those large allocations are happening. This program has multiple forks and one of those forks is shooting the RES memory to 11.0G as you can see below (cropped screenshot of htop).

[image: cropped screenshot of htop]

My question is in general how to debug those large memory allocation without reading through the code for `malloc`/`calloc` etc.?

Right now I'm looking at the core dump through gdb but this `bt` output doesn't tell the picture where those allocations are happening.

I was looking for something similar to dotnet dump analyse or PerfView.

Comment: You don't have to read through the code, let `grep` do it for you. `strace` the program and watch for the `brk`, `sbrk` or `mmap` syscalls. `valgrind` with an appropriate tool (see valgrind tool selection) could also be a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is in general how to debug those large memory allocation without reading through the code for malloc/calloc etc.?

1. Reading through `malloc` etc. *will not help* with your original question.
2. You want to use a heap profiler. TCmalloc has support for [heap profiling](https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heapprofile.html), which can tell you a *lot* about your application's heap use. There are other heap profilers as well.

This [article](http://postbits.de/heap-profiling-with-tcmalloc.html) may be helpful as well.

P.S. Extracting heap profiling info from an existing `core` dump is possible, but *hard*. And you are unlikely to find out the allocation stack trace(s) anyway.

Your best bet is to set up heap profiler and reproduce the problem, rather than trying to recover the info post mortem.